# Returning value that was passed into a method

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have a method on an interface:

```
string DoSomething(string whatever);
```

I want to mock this with MOQ, so that it returns whatever was passed in - something like:

```
_mock.Setup( theObject => theObject.DoSomething( It.IsAny<string>( ) ) )
   .Returns( [the parameter that was passed] ) ;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 751, accepted):

You can use a lambda with an input parameter, like so:

```
.Returns((string myval) => { return myval; });
```

Or slightly more readable:

```
.Returns<string>(x => x);
```

Comment: Seems quite easy until you need to do this for a method with **7 arguments**...

When I inspected `IReturns` in Moq, it defines `Returns` for **4 arguments at most**. 

Any easy way to get around that? /I mean except modifying Moq source/

Comment: ok, it's defined for up to **9 arguments** in `Moq` v `4.0.0.0`. solved :)

Comment: @mizukinakeshu I'd consider a bit of a refactor on a 9 argument method as it sounds like the class/method is doing too much. Perhaps refactor the 9 parameters into a settings class or struct to help you later?

Comment: @TheSenator Agree, I don't reacall already what this was about but I guess I was just hacking some unit tests together for already existing code I was not to modify, otherwise this number of arguments definitely calls for refactoring.

Comment: Just a note as this confused me: The string in `.Returns<string>` refers to the input parameter(s) and not the values you are returning.

Comment: This is the same approach taken for when mocking add and remove methods on DbSet in EF6.

Comment: @TheSenator at a previous job we had a build failure because there was a signature change from 62 to 63 arguments! (It was a search method FWIW, but obviously in desperate need of a refactor)

Comment: @Jim In any case it must match the type at hand. It's the same for input and output as per the question.

Answer (score 388):

Even more useful, if you have multiple parameters you can access any/all of them with:

```
_mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>()))
     .Returns((string a, string b, string c) => string.Concat(a,b,c));
```

You always need to reference all the arguments, to match the method's signature, even if you're only going to use one of them.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is exactly what you need to do. Anything else throws a "number of expected arguments" exception.

Comment: Yea, definitely allot easier to read and works with `ReturnsAsync` too!

Comment: This answer saved the day.  Note (future readers), you can take it a bit further as well.             .Returns((string a, string b, string c) => 
     {
 string d = "wow";
 return string.Concat(a,b,c,d);
    }
 );

Comment: Personally, this is a much better answer. I have very little knowledge of Moq but still I understood it immediately.

Comment: For methods returning void I used .Callback((string a, Exception b, string c) => throw new Exception(b.Message));

Comment: The fact that I had to (and could) declare the variables in the lambda was completely new for me. 
I wrote (a,b,c) =>and not (string a, string b, string c)=>

Comment: I think you are missing one closing bracket

Comment: 11 years and no one had noticed! Added it now.

Answer (score 96):

The generic `Returns<T>` method can handle this situation nicely.

```
_mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(x => x);
```

Or if the method requires multiple inputs, specify them like so:

```
_mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((string x, int y) => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are not using Moq, there's a way with NSubstitute.

```
mock.Method(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(callInfo =>
    {
         var arg1 = callInfo[0].ToString();
         var arg2 = callInfo[1].ToString();
         var argN = callInfo[n-1].ToString();
         return arg1 + arg2 + argN; //or whatever
    });
```