# Moq: Return value passed as value into method as IEnumerable<T>

Tags: lambda, mocking, moq

I found the post titled [MOQ: Returning value that was passed into a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996602/moq-returning-value-that-was-passed-into-a-method) which was quite helpful in that I can get one of the values passed in to provide as a return value.

The issue I am faced with is that I need to convert the value (a string) to an IEnumerable as the one and only item in the enumeration, and I am getting tripped up on the syntax for doing so.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var aggregator = new Mock<IUrlAggregator>();
        aggregator
            .Setup(x => x.ProcessUrl(It.IsAny<IUrlFileLineInfo>()))
            .Returns((IUrlFileLineInfo x) => x.Url); <-- Need to return IEnumerable<string> here, not string
```

The ProcessUrl signature looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> ProcessUrl(IUrlFileLineInfo urlInfo);
```

And the IUrlFileLineInfo interface:

```
public interface IUrlFileLineInfo
{
    string Url { get; set; }
    string Mode { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I convert the string value to an IEnumerable within the context of a lamba expression (through the .Returns() method)?

**Update**

This is what I ended up with. Thanks for the help. Hopefully this will help others who are new to lambdas.

```
var aggregator = new Mock<IUrlAggregator>();
        aggregator
            .Setup(x => x.ProcessUrl(It.IsAny<IUrlFileLineInfo>()))
            .Returns((IUrlFileLineInfo x) => new List<string>() { x.Url });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about returning an array with the one item `x.Url` ?

```
var aggregator = new Mock<IUrlAggregator>();
        aggregator
            .Setup(x => x.ProcessUrl(It.IsAny<IUrlFileLineInfo>()))
            .Returns((IUrlFileLineInfo x) => new [] { x.Url });
```

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it. I just tried a similar solution and it worked. It didn't dawn on me until after I posted this to declare the array after the =>.