# Returning value that was passed into a ReturnsAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I need method `CreateAsync` to return what it receives (the same `List<enteties>`)

```
Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> CreateAsync(IEnumerable<Entity> entities, CancellationToken? token = null);
```

I'm trying to mock a repository's method like that:

```
repository.Setup(i => i.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<List<enteties>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((List<enteties> x, object y) => x);
```

But it returns empty `IEnumareble`

Comment: It is up to you to provide mocked values. You know what list goes into CreateAsync, re-use the same list in ReturnAsync.

Comment: Could you please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: An uninitialized MOQ will return `null`/`default`. So if your setup is returning an empty `IEnumerable` then you must be passing it one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning value that was passed into a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996602/returning-value-that-was-passed-into-a-method)

Answer (score 0):

Moq can do what you want here and give back the same list it was given. Your only problem is the type mismatch in the argument matchers.

The interface uses `CancellationToken?` but the `Setup` in your question uses `It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()`.

Change it to `It.IsAny<CancellationToken?>()` and it works:

```cs
repository.Setup(i => i.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<List<Entity>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken?>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((List<Entity> x, object y) => x);
```